# How to get multiple select box values and texts together using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a select box and user can select multiple colors
so I want to get values and texts of selected options with bellow code I just get texts or just get values but I want both

```
  selected_colors = $('.selectpicker option:selected')
                .toArray().map(item => item.text);
                console.log(selected_colors);
```

it gives me this

```
(2) ["بنفش", "نارنجی روشن"]0: "بنفش"1: "نارنجی روشن"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

btw "نارنجی روشن" and ... are colors name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
selected_colors = $('.selectpicker option:selected').toArray().map(item => ({'text':item.text, 'value':item.value}));

console.log(selected_colors);
```